# PHP-LARAVEL be published on this date

Tags: laravel

I want a share that I created and saved in the database to be activated from passive on a certain date. I couldn't find the most correct way to do this.

How should I code this?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use the scheduler: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling
You have to post some specific code if you want any more help. Otherwise your question is too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a date in a 'publish_at' column on the database.

When you query the database to show items, you can include a where statement so that only items that are publish_at in the past are displayed.

For instance, if this were a Post model;

```
$posts = Post::where('publish_at', '<', now())->get();
```

Comment: Yes, I understand, I will implement it, but the question mark in my mind is this.

Suppose the database is not queried for a long time.
 For example, he was not questioned for 6 hours. If there is a post that must be published within 6 hours, it will be published late. I was looking for a more dynamic way

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'published'. Are you sending it somewhere or doing something other than displaying it on a request?